# Deserialization with Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have a User interface:

```
public interface User{
    public static final String USER_KEY = "UK";
    public String getSessionKey();
    public List<Ties> getTies(); 
}
```

And some hierarchy of User interface:
abstract class UserKind1 implements User
abstract class UserKind2 implements User

```
public interface Ties{
    public String getId();
}
```

Implementation of UserKind{1,2} is in UserKind{1,2}Factory, for example:

```
public class UserKind1Factory {

    public static UserKind1 createUserKind1(List<Ties> tieses){
        return new UserKind1Impl(tieses);
    }
    public static UserKind1 createUserKind1(List<Ties> tieses, long sessionMaxTime){
        return new UserKind1Impl(tieses, sessionMaxTime);
    }

    private static class UserKind1Impl extends UserKind1{
        private List<Ties> legalTies;
        private long sessionMaxTime = 18000000;

        public UserKind1Impl(List<Ties> ties){
            this.ties = ties;
        }
        public UserKind1Impl(List<Ties> ties, long sessionMaxTime){
            this.ties = ties;
            this.sessionMaxTime = sessionMaxTime;
        } 
        ...
    }
}
```

and the same impl for UserKind2 and Ties.

**Question:** How correctlly use Jackson for deserialization UserKind1?

I do some modifications with originally code:

```
public class UserKind1Factory {

    @JsonCreator
    public static UserKind1 createUserKind1(@JsonProperty("ties") Ties[] ties, @JsonProperty("sessionMaxTime") long sessionMaxTime) {
        ArrayList tiesList = new ArrayList<Ties>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ties.length; i++) {
            tiesList.add(ties[i]);
        }
        return new UserKind1Impl(tiesList, sessionMaxTime);
    }

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
public static class UserKind1Impl extends UserKind1{
...
}
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TiesFactory.TiesImpl.class, name = "ties")})
public interface Ties

public class TiesFactory {
@JsonCreator
    public static LegalTies createLegalTies(@JsonProperty("id") String id)

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
    public static class TiesImpl implements Ties{

... and get json:

{
  "@class" : "ua.company.model.user.impl.UserKind1Factory$UserKind1Impl",
  "legalTies" : [ {
    "@class" : "ua.company.model.user.impl.TiesFactory$TiesImpl",
    "id" : "100500"    
  }, {
    "@class" : "ua.company.model.user.impl.TiesFactory$TiesImpl",
    "id" : "200600"   
  } ],
  "sessionMaxTime" : 100501,
  "sessionKey" : "UK"
}
```

but when I try deserialize this, it's crash with exception:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor
found for type [simple type, class
ua.company.model.user.impl.UserKind1Factory$UserKind1Impl]: can not
instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?) 
at [Source: [B@a85aa40; line: 2, column: 64]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class ua.company.model.user.impl.UserKind1Factory$UserKind1Impl]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?) at [Source: [B@a85aa40; line: 2, column: 64]
```

**The exception it self has the solution all you need to do is create the default constructor for your POJO class**

Comment: Yes, it's right, but how about question? How to deserialize objects, the realization of which is in the Factory?

Comment: Which question please?

Comment: How to deserialize objects, the realization of which is in the Factory?

Comment: http://programmerbruce.blogspot.in/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html  see it may helps you

Comment: Thank Sagar Pudi. In that post, we register or specify impl class, but for this case UserKind1Factory has private impl.

Comment: Unfortunately, I not found any solution for deserialize object with Factory method. Temporarily, I make public class UserKind1Impl implement UserKind1.